# Converter class in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

May someone please explain the converter class? What is the equivalent of  a converter class in MVC? as in would it be similar to a  model or ??

```
public  class Converter
{


    public CountryDTO CountriesToCountryDTO(Countries e)
    {
        return new CountryDTO
        {
            CountryId = e.CountryId,
            CountryName = e.CountryName
        };
    }

    public  List<CountryDTO> LCountriesToCountryDTO(List<Countries> e)        
    {
        List<CountryDTO> lstCountryDTO = e.Select(
          country => new CountryDTO()
          {
              CountryId = country.CountryId,
              CountryName = country.CountryName
          }).ToList();
        return lstCountryDTO; 
    }
```

Comment: This is C#, so a convertor in MVC would be no different, unless you're using VB (which you're not as your tags suggest).

Comment: Not sure there's anything to explain. A converter class converts things. The one you've shown converts from the `Countries` class to its equivalent DTO, and back again. It's just a fairly simple C# class, so there's no difference between a converter class in MVC to one in anything else written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

This is plain simple c# class, not anything MVC specific, not model related.
functions them selves convert Countries and list of countries objects into respective DTO objects.
A model in MVC would countain one or more properties able to hold data (variables, lists, objects) without functions and their implementation like in this example.

It would look something like this :

```
public class Converter
{
    public CountryDTO CountryDTO { get; set; }
    public List<CountryDTO> CountriesDTO {get; set;}
}
```

Altho i doubt that makes any sense in your context.

Comment: Thanks a million for the explanations. In my context I just needed to convert the DTO to list which I figured does not necessarily have to be done with a converter class